# how to use jsf flows using flowHandler

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, faces-flow

Hi i would go through steps of flow in backing bean using a method:

```
transition(FacesContext context, Flow sourceFlow, Flow targetFlow, FlowCallNode outboundCallNode, String toViewId);
```

of

```
javax.faces.flow.FlowHandler
```

or some other way

for example:

```
public void startFlow(){

    // in this example we dont use jsf tags 
    // (<h:commandButton /> and <h:commandLink />) to navigate user through flow steps

    FlowHandler handler = context.getApplication().getFlowHandler();
    Flow targetFlow = handler.getFlow(context, "", "registerFlow");
    boolean isAdmin = checkIfAdmin();

    if(isAdmin){
      // here we forward user to viewNode of flow that name step1
      handler.transition(context, null, targetFlow, null, "step1");
    }
    else{
      // here we forward user to viewNode of flow that name step1ForAdmin
      handler.transition(context, null, targetFlow, null, "step1ForAdmin");
    }

}
```

It is possible to do that in backing bean? or meaby is other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

FlowHandler is an abstract class, which is intended for internal use of the JSF framework. If you want to navigate to one or another entry node of a JSF flow simply return the name of the target node for navigation (Only HTTP POST is allowed). Or you can enter into the flow through a Method Call Node or a Switch Node and implement there the required navigation conditions.

You can read [this](https://blog.oio.de/2014/02/12/a-comprehensive-example-of-jsf-faces-flow/) Post and download the sample project from GitHub. It will illustrate you on some techniques related to JSF flows.